# Does Lenovo IdeaPad 330s 15IKB 81F5 Support Western Digital SN Black 770 SSD

Tags: ssd, lenovo-laptop

I have Lenovo IdeaPad 330s, It comes with 1TB HDD, I want to know if, my laptop supports WD Black SN770. I know that my PC has a M.2 slot but not sure if it's PCIe or NVMe.

Here's the model on Lenovo official website: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/330s-15ikb/81f5/81f5006fus/yd04fk6k?linkTrack=Caps%3ABody_SearchProduct&searchType=6&keyWordSearch=YD04FK6K

Does my PC support, WD Black SN770 which is a NVMe SSD, I think my laptop may have SATA Slot, with M+B, does the M+B key slot support M key, I know this might not give me the rated performance, but I want to keep the SSD for future purposes too.

Can you please tell if it's Compatible

Answer (score 1):

[NVMe *is* PCIe x4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVMe#M.2)

As per [TFM](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330s-14ikb_330s-14ikbx_330s-15ikb_330s-15ikbx_hmm_201903.pdf) (which I strongly advice you download, since it contains instructions on taking apart the laptop, and consumer grade machines are designed to be less maintainable in many cases) - it definitely supports m.2 PCIe/NVMe SSDs

[image]

There's no mentions of SATA in the hardware manual - and strangely its a little worse than some others I've seen since it dosen't actually tell you anything about slots

In *theory* you need to make sure yours is a 2280 drive, but frankly I've never seen one another size outside very specific applications like thin clients

So yeah, your drive should work with no issues

Comment: Hey, So I just got the back panel opened up I found the Intel Optane MEMORY the 16GB one as mentioned before, the optane memory card inserted has a B+M key

Comment: Do you think a SSD with M key will be supported in that slot